# Is it possible to use inline CSS to reference dynamic images in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Sorry if the title was a bit unclear, I couldn't think of any other way to phrase it.

So I want to know if it's possible to use inline CSS (`<div class="" style="background-image: url();"` and put the dynamically created images in there. So if I want a user to upload a banner, I want the background image of the div to be the image. Is this possible?

So for example

The user uploads a photo and it goes to `/media/`

Then normally to reference it, I would do

```html
<img class="user-image" src="{% user.userprofile.image.url %}">
```

However, what if I wanted to set it as a background image.
In the CSS document, I want to do this:

```css
.user-image-div {
    background-image: url({% user.userprofile.image.url %})
}
```

However, this doesn't work. So my question is, is it possible to use inline CSS in the HTML document to get around this?

So like

```html
<div class="user-image-div" style="background-image: url({% user.userprofile.image.url %};)">

<!-- code here -->

</div>
```

Would this work? I don't have access to Django at the moment, so I will be able to test it out in a few days

Comment: Url is a template tag: `{% url "app:viewname" kwarg=value ... %}` or `{% url "app:viewname" arg1 arg2 ... %}`

Answer (score 0):

Inline css works with the `url` function.
You just have to make sure that the path you're sending is something like:

"/my/user/image/"
instead of
"http://www.example.com/my/user/image"